# How to replace the first element of each array with an element from seperate list cyclically? python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

For example, if i have a 3d array of size:

```
array_3d = np.zeros((3, 3, 3))
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

How to get the output of:

```
[[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [2. 0. 0. 0.]
  [3. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[2. 0. 0. 0.]
  [3. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [2. 0. 0. 0.]]

 [[3. 0. 0. 0.]
  [1. 0. 0. 0.]
  [2. 0. 0. 0.]
  [3. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

I tried something like:

```
for i in array_3d:
   for items in zip(cycle(list1), i):
          i.append(list1)
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if `array_3d.shape[1] != len(list1)`, you can do the following:

```
array_3d = np.zeros((3, 4, 4))
list1 = [1, 2, 3]

# calculate the total number elements required for a single column
fsize = array_3d.shape[0] * array_3d.shape[1]

# use tile to repeat elements in list1 so it has the same size as fsize
col = np.tile(list1, fsize // len(list1) + 1)[:fsize]
col
# [1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3]

# assign list1 to column 0
array_3d[:,:,0] = col.reshape(array_3d.shape[:2])
array_3d
#[[[1. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0. 0.]]

# [[2. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0. 0.]]

# [[3. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0. 0.]]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are defining a 3 * 3 * 3 tensor but your desired output is 3 * 4 * 4. That aside, if you want that output in a 3 * 3 * 3:

```
array_3d[:, :, 0] = list1
```

If you want that output in a 3 * 4 * 4:

```
list_cycle = cycle(list1)
for i in range(array_3d.shape[0]):
    for j in range(array_3d.shape[1]):
        array_3d[i, j, 0] = next(list_cycle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have the following setup:

```
array_3d = np.zeros((3, 4, 4))
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

You could use advanced indexing to select the columns you want to modify:

```
array_3d[:,np.r_[:4], 0]

# array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0.],
#        [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

It looks like you want fill these 3 columns with `list1` and wrap around out-of-bound indices:

```
array_3d[:,np.r_[:4], 0] = np.tile(list1, 4).reshape(3,4)
```

Output in `array_3d`:

```
array([[[1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [2., 0., 0., 0.],
        [3., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[2., 0., 0., 0.],
        [3., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [2., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[3., 0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [2., 0., 0., 0.],
        [3., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

This is the same as doing `array_3d[:,:,0] = np.tile(list1, 4).reshape(3,4)` (just like the answer given by Psidom)